# Can I upload files using ajax as shown below?

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using ajax. Can I upload the file using this method? I am currently only getting the file name.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploadbutton").click(function() {
        var filename = $("#file").val();
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "addFile.do",
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           data: {file: filename},
          success: function(){
               alert( "Data Uploaded: ");
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

Comment: No you can't do that way... What is #file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like this, Please refer the below URL..It will help you, You can also implement with Progress bar.

http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/